# My WP site redirects from HTTPS to HTTP but posts don't

Tags: wordpress

Here are contents of my `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add home url and site url in your wp-config file

```
define('WP_HOME','http:example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http:example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code
 /**
     * Redirect WordPress front end https URLs to http without a plugin
     *
     * Necessary when running forced SSL in admin and you don't want links to the front end to remain https.
     *
     * @link http://blackhillswebworks.com/?p=5088
     */

```
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bhww_ssl_template_redirect', 1 );

    function bhww_ssl_template_redirect() {

        if ( is_ssl() && ! is_admin() ) {

            if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http' ) ) {

                wp_redirect( preg_replace( '|^https://|', 'http://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 301 );
                exit();

            } else {

                wp_redirect( 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
                exit();

            }

        }

    }
```