# how to change wordpress blog to https

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

My Wordpress site is behind an AWS elastic cache load balancer. When I change the URL over to HTTPS the css/js fail to load. I have tried various plugins that force HTTPS but this seems to be the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Had you defined the site url and home url in wp-config.php file.

Also if you added static http path in php files then change it to https:

```
define('site_url',https://www.example.com);
define('home_url',https://www.example.com);
```

Comment: I chanaged via the UI and in the wp-config but this still leaves the site broken as static resources are still being loaded over HTTP

Comment: you mean to say images and all come from http path right?

Comment: Here is one ticket that resolve the same problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594360/my-wp-site-redirects-from-https-to-http-but-posts-dont/35594594#35594594

Comment: that seems to be for redirecting HTTPS-> HTTP I'm trying to do the opposite

Comment: You have to do opposite of it 
define('WP_HOME','https:example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https:example.com');
and one more thing 

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

Also in options table change home url and site url from http://example.com to https:example.com
and add this plugin with all this above configuration
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-https/